# How to change attribute value of anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I a have an anchor tag with default object values

```
<a type="hidden"id="submitExport" href="@Url.Action("ExportAllToExcel", new { strvoicerecordfetchquery = "", nSelectAllten = "", bSelectAll = "" })" ></a>
```

I want to change values of
strvoicerecordfetchquery ,nSelectAllten and bSelectAll accordingly from script

Comment: do provide some code mate..

Comment: a type="hidden"? are you sure?

Comment: can u explain what is <a type="hidden" ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you got a problem with quotes inside quotes in the href attribute
and because of that the jquery prop method returns not the whole value of the href

use this html code for your a tag

```
<a type="hidden"id="submitExport" href="@Url.Action('ExportAllToExcel', new { strvoicerecordfetchquery = '', nSelectAllten = '', bSelectAll = '' })" ></a>
```

Comment: I want to change values of all attribute using script and then changing values click should be call on anchor tag to pass arguments to the controller function

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').prop("href", 'Url.Action("ExportAllToExcel", new { newval = "", dd = "", bSenew valdd= "" })');
```